# Rx Amb extension

Tags: c#, silverlight, caching, enterprise-library, system.reactive

I'm working with the Reactive framework for Silverlight and would like to achieve the following.

I am try to create a typical data provider for a Silverlight client that also takes advantage of the caching framework available in MS Ent Lib. The scenarios requires that I must check in the cache for the key-value pair before hitting the WCF data client.

By using the Rx extension Amb, I am able to pull the data from the cache or WCF data client, whichever returns first, but how can I stop the WCF client from executing the call if the values is in the cache?

I would also like to consider racing conditions, e.g. if the first subscriber requests some data and the provider is fetching data from the WCF data client (async), how do I prevent subsequent async requests from doing the same thing (at this stage, the cache has yet to be populated).

Comment: Are you sure you want to try both at the same time and go for the one that returns first? Or would you prefer to try them in order? Trying them at the same time means that your data service will be hit every time, regardless of whether the app uses the cache or not - this doesn't seem like the intended behaviour.

Comment: @yamen You are absolutely correct that this behaviour is unintended, I am looking for an alternative to this.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://github.com/github/akavache

Comment: Thank you Paul kindly for the library. I will keep it in mind if I run out of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it with an extension method with the following signature:

```
IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, R> cache,
    Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch,
    IScheduler scheduler) where R : class
```

Effectively what this did was take in the source observable and return an observable that would match each input value with its output value.

To get each output value it would check the cache first. If the value exists in the cache it used that. If not it would spin up the `fetch` function **only** on values that weren't in the cache. If all of the values were in the cache then the `fetch` function would never be spun up - so no service connection set up penalty, etc.

I'll give you the code, but it's based on a slightly different version of the extension method that uses a `Maybe<T>` monad - so you might find you need to fiddle with the implementation.

Here it is:

```
    public static IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, R> cache, Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch, IScheduler scheduler)
        where R : class
    {
        return source.FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(t => cache(t).ToMaybe(null), fetch, scheduler);
    }

    public static IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Maybe<R>> cache, Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var results = new Subject<R>();

        var disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

        var loop = new EventLoopScheduler();
        disposables.Add(loop);

        var sourceDone = false;
        var pairsDone = true;
        var exception = (Exception)null;

        var fetchIn = new Subject<T>();
        var fetchOut = (IObservable<R>)null;
        var pairs = (IObservable<KeyValuePair<int, R>>)null;

        var lookup = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        var list = new List<Maybe<R>>();
        var cursor = 0;

        Action checkCleanup = () =>
        {
            if (sourceDone && pairsDone)
            {
                if (exception == null)
                {
                    results.OnCompleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    results.OnError(exception);
                }
                loop.Schedule(() => disposables.Dispose());
            }
        };

        Action dequeue = () =>
        {
            while (cursor != list.Count)
            {
                var mr = list[cursor];
                if (mr.HasValue)
                {
                    results.OnNext(mr.Value);
                    cursor++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        Action<KeyValuePair<int, R>> nextPairs = kvp =>
        {
            list[kvp.Key] = Maybe<R>.Something(kvp.Value);
            dequeue();
        };

        Action<Exception> errorPairs = ex =>
        {
            fetchIn.OnCompleted();
            pairsDone = true;
            exception = ex;
            checkCleanup();
        };

        Action completedPairs = () =>
        {
            pairsDone = true;
            checkCleanup();
        };

        Action<T> sourceNext = t =>
        {
            var mr = cache(t);
            list.Add(mr);
            if (mr.IsNothing)
            {
                lookup[t] = list.Count - 1;
                if (fetchOut == null)
                {
                    pairsDone = false;
                    fetchOut = fetch(fetchIn.ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool));
                    pairs = fetchIn.Select(x => lookup[x]).Zip(fetchOut, (i, r2) => new KeyValuePair<int, R>(i, r2));
                    disposables.Add(pairs.ObserveOn(loop).Subscribe(nextPairs, errorPairs, completedPairs));
                }
                fetchIn.OnNext(t);
            }
            else
            {
                dequeue();
            }
        };

        Action<Exception> errorSource = ex =>
        {
            sourceDone = true;
            exception = ex;
            fetchIn.OnCompleted();
            checkCleanup();
        };

        Action completedSource = () =>
        {
            sourceDone = true;
            fetchIn.OnCompleted();
            checkCleanup();
        };

        disposables.Add(source.ObserveOn(loop).Subscribe(sourceNext, errorSource, completedSource));

        return results.ObserveOn(scheduler);
    }
```

---

Example usage would look like this:

You would have a source of the indices that you want to fetch:

```
IObservable<X> source = ...
```

You would have a function that can get values from the cache and an action that can put them in (and both should be thread-safe):

```
Func<X, Y> getFromCache = x => ...;
Action<X, Y> addToCache = (x, y) => ...;
```

Then you would have the actual call to go get the data from your database or service:

```
Func<X, Y> getFromService = x => ...;
```

Then you could define `fetch` like so:

```
Func<IObservable<X>, IObservable<Y>> fetch =
    xs => xs.Select(x =>
    {
        var y = getFromService(x);
        addToCache(x, y);
        return y;
    });
```

And finally you can make your query by calling the following:

```
IObservable<Y> results =
    source.FromCacheOrFetch(
        getFromCache,
        fetch,
        Scheduler.ThreadPool);
```

Of course you would need to subscribe to the result to make the computation take place.

Comment: Could you please show me a short example of this extension's usage. This one looks like it's the solution I'm after.

Comment: @TriQ - I added an example - it's fairly basic but it might help.

Comment: One question, what happens when two subscriber wishes to fetch at the same time (the time it takes for the service call to come back and fill the cache). Does this mean that the service will be hit twice?

Comment: @TriQ - there's a chance that some of the items might get asked for twice, but it does try to fill the cache in as quickly as possible so it's not likely.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `Amb` is not the right way to go, since that will hit both the cache and the service every time. What does EntLib return you if the cache is a miss?

Note that `Observable.Timeout` is a reasonable alternative:

```
cache(<paramters>).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), service<paramters>);
```

But clearly it's not a great idea to timeout if you want instead process the return from EntLib and act appropriately instead.

I'm not seeing why this is necessarily a Reactive Extensions problem.

Comment: The cache would return null if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, which is probably less fully featured than @Enigmativity's solution could be something along the lines of:

```
public IObservable<T> GetCachedValue<TKey, TResult>(TKey key, Func<TKey, TResult> getFromCache, Func<TKey, TResult> getFromSource)
{
    return getFromCache(<key>).Concat(getFromSource(<key>).Take(1);
}
```

This is just a loosely formed idea, you'd need to add:

- A mechanism to add the item to the cache, or assume getFromSource caches the result
- Some kind of thread safety to prevent multiple hits on the source for the same uncached key (if required)
- getFromCache would need to return Observable.Empty() if the item wasn't in the cache.

But if you want something simple, it's not a bad place to start.